# Overriding jsSocials Link to Execute Custom Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to override the default function that is included with [`jsSocials`](http://js-socials.com/) to simply execute my custom share function (that allows changing Facebook meta)

Default `jsSocials` HTML

```
<div class="jssocials-share jssocials-share-facebook"><a href="#" class="jssocials-share-link"><i class="fa fa-facebook jssocials-share-logo"></i><span class="jssocials-share-label">Share</span></a></div>
```

New Share function using [`shareOverrideOGMeta`](http://drib.tech/programming/dynamically-change-facebook-open-graph-meta-data-javascript)

```
shareOverrideOGMeta(window.location.href, shareTitle, shareDesc, shareThumb);
```

Seems simple, but this isn't working for some reason

```
$("div.jssocials-share-facebook *").on('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  shareOverrideOGMeta(window.location.href, shareTitle, shareDesc, shareThumb);
  console.log("share should be overridden");
});
```

How can I go about making this work another way, or fixing what I am doing wrong if it's that simple?

Note: The new share code has been tested using keypress and is working well.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by unbinding and rebinding the `click` handler INSIDE the function that set up the social sharing.

```
  $(".jssocials-share-facebook *").unbind("click").on("click", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    shareOverrideOGMeta(window.location.href, shareTitle, shareDesc, shareThumb);
  });
```